# Prevent vim from escaping parantheses when using %:p

Tags: windows, vim, explorer

I have created a command in vim to open the current file in Explorer using the following:
`command! E silent !start explorer /select,"%:p"`

If I use this command to try to open my _vimrc file (located at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc) it opens the wrong directory.  It appears that %:p is escaping the parentheses around "x86" when it starts Explorer which results in it trying to navigate to C:\Program Files \(x86\)\Vim\_vimrc

The part that I find weird is that if in vim I type the following command:
`:echo expand("%:p")`
it prints the path without escaping the parentheses.

Also, if I try hard coding the path in the command it open correctly.  This leads me to believe that it is some weird quirk with vim resolving %:p when using the ! command.

Does anyone know of a way to prevent %:p from escaping the parentheses when using the ! command?  I read through the help for both %:p and :!, but wasn't able to find anything to address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know whether there is a way to do so, but using `!...%` in *any* script is a bad idea as it is impossible (at least on POSIX systems, AFAIK it is not so on windows where `"` is forbidden in file name). In case you need to pass a filename to a shell command use `:execute`+`shellescape()`+`expand()`:

```
command! E :execute 'silent !start explorer /select,'.shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I had thought about somehow using expand() in the command, but couldn't figure out how to make it work.  For some reason it didn't occur to me to use :execute.